App Store Connect says "An error has occured. Try again" when I try to create In-App Purchase
I've been trying to create in-app purchases for the last few hours but every time I do, App Store Connect says "An error has occured. Try Again". I was able to create in app purchases yesterday but now this error is showing up.
I've tried some of the solutions for related errors. I've tried to use incognito, switched browser from Chrome to Safari and even switched from Mac to laptop but this error still persists.
Does anyone know a solution to this?

What do you mean by “to create in-app purchases”? Are you trying to buy something within an app or are you trying to list options within an app in the App Store as a developer so that they can be purchased by others?

Do you have an unsigned Paid Apps Agreement?

Select "Business" on the top navigation.
Select your business.
Under "Agreements" check "Paid Apps Agreement"
On the right hand "Status" column there will be a button to view and agree.

It would be nice if Apple gave more information in the error message.

Hey sorry for the late response. Yeah the issue was that the paid apps agreement was updated and had to be signed again.
